# Limiting the amount of elements on JQuery Autocomplete Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kheAn/

In JQuery Autocomplete, you can use `slice` to limit, but I am not sure how to do it with this plugin.

I want to limit the amount of elements that are shown in the autocomplete drop down.

Right now, all elements are being shown. I want to show just the top 10 that are closest to what the user typed.

How can I limit the elements shown?

Also, is there any better solution for this than the code I currently have? I have heard that I should be using Node.js and/or bootstrap.

Comment: Node.js and Bootstrap have nothing to do with this… what have you heard them being recommended for?

Comment: http://sandglaz.github.io/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/

Comment: @rynah maybe just because Bootstrap provides an autocomplete plugin ? But you're right about NodeJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About NodeJS, it is a JavaScript server-side language, who is pretty and quite easy to get started with, but I don't think there is a special interest for an autocomplete feature ?!

I don't exactly know how tagit works, but if you want to use bootstrap to manage it, you can easily use the "typeahead" plugin and set the items option to the max number of items you wants.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

```
$('#demo2').typeahead({
    source: availableTags,
    items: 10
});
```

EDIT: according to the tagit.js documentation, and the jQuery autocomplete one.

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#autocomplete-object

> Allows overriding the source and select options that are set by
>   default, as well as adding any other options you want to pass to the
>   jQuery UI Autocomplete widget, such as minLength or delay.
>
> The autocomplete.source should be overridden if you want to use custom
>   autocompletion sources, like an Ajax / XHR response.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You cannot easily add an option to limit the max number of items displayed, however you could  overwrite the source with a function where you can limit the response items inside !

I keep thinking that bootstrap is more adapted to your needs, and it doesn't require jQuery-UI.

EDIT:

After discussion, this plugin should probably be the one you are looking for !

http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

```
$('#demo2').tagsManager({
    typeahead: true,
    typeaheadSource: availableTags
});
```

Comment: Bootstrap and TypeAhead are certainly helpful, but the I am unable to add the bubble tag effect on the tags that I have already added into the textbox. Instead, they simply show up in normal text as opposed to the background effect that can be seen in the original JSFiddle.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to that while editing my answer. But your tagautocomplete plugin seems to be able to use bootstrap options, I'm trying to edit your Fiddle with it !

Comment: One problem is that tagautocomplete works only with contenteditable HTML elements, that's supported only recently on mobile browsers (don't know if you care about it ? http://caniuse.com/contenteditable)
 and a second thing is that it should be preceded by a special character as # or @. (not sure if you like it ?)

Comment: Well, if I absolutely have to compromise on the special character issue, then I will settle for it. So yes, I would fine keeping it. Also, I don't really care about the mobile browser versions, so as long as it works on the desktop, its good.

Comment: Okay, so maybe this updated Fiddle is something you would fine interesting ? http://jsfiddle.net/kheAn/1/
Remember that you have to tape a # before the word you are looking for.
And that it only works for words that begin with what you are typing, not that only contains it !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29449/discussion-between-demcodelines-and-flo-schield-bobby)